# Agregar nueva fila y autosumar +1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde agrego una una fila  a una tabla. Tengo un indicador que es un numero.

Quiero poder al momento de agregar una nueva fila este indicador incremente en uno.

Ejemplo si el indicador es `10`, y agrego una fila este debe llevar el num `11` y en caso que agregue otro este también debería sumar uno `12`.

Mi idea es crear una funcion donde me sume la ultima fila de la tabla y me agrege +1 al valor de ese indicador.

```js
var i = 1;
$('.add').click(function() {
    i++;
    
    $('#tbl_cotizacion').find('tbody').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td></td> <td></td>  <td></td> <td width="5%"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_remove">x</button></td></tr>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


     
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>4 </td>
                <td>Falso </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light add'> <i class='fa fa-add' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; add </button> </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: el indicador debe empezar en 10? o sólo es un ejemplo y comienza en 1?

Comment: en teoria ya lo estas haciendo al presionar el boton incrementar i++ , que es lo que no has podido lograr?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera este empieza en 10, en otros caso empieza en distinto numero

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que te falta es agregar ese *flag* o *contador* que estas utilizando en el cuerpo de la tabla que creas a través de `JQuery`

```js
var i = 1;
$('.add').click(function() {
    i++;
    
    $('#tbl_cotizacion').find('tbody').append(`<tr id="row${i}"><td>${i}</td> <td></td>  <td></td> <td width="5%"><button type="button" name="remove" id="${i}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_remove">x</button></td></tr>`);
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># Indicador</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">Componente</th>
                  <th width="5%"></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>4 </td>
                <td>Falso </td>
                 <td>  <button type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-slack waves-effect waves-light add'> <i class='fa fa-add' aria-hidden='true'></i> &nbsp; add </button> </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si te fijas el único cambio que hice fue agregar la variable `i` al cuerpo del `<td></td>`.
Adicionalmente te recomiendo utilizar la **[interpolación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)** que se incluyo desde la versión de JavaScript, ya que son mucho más limpias de utilizar que concatenar cadenas.

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: No quiero un contador quiero un sumar +1 al ultimo indicador de la tabla. Ejemplo si borro uno me deberia recarcular los indicadores.

Comment: En ese caso si por ejemplo creo 4 filas que van desde la 10 a la 14, y elimino la 12, tu quieres que los indicadores YA creados cambien también?

Comment: Si, presionar el btn borrar elimina la fila 12, este re calcula el numero `13` => `12` y el `14` => `13`